On ubuntu 24.04 and 24.10 is there a presentation mode that prevents screen going blank?
As the title says, is there a way to activate a presentation mode that prevents the screen going blank after a few minutes of inactivity?
I installed caffeine and caffeine-indicator, which worked fine on 22.04 LTS, but it no longer works on more recent versions of Ubuntu.
One workaround is to go to settings, "power saving", and disable "screen blank" but this is not practical.

This question is similar to: How to get a lock-screen inhibitor like caffeine working in Ubuntu 24.04?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
